# Is the following title correct? Document streams Segmentation and Classification

Tags: grammar

```
"Document streams Segmentation and Classification"
```

What I mean by this title is that i have a stream or a flow of documents and i want to separate these documents and classify them into for example insurance, receipt documents.

Does it sound correct in english?

Thank you.

Comment: I would put a colon after streams:

Comment: why @mplungjan? will it make the title clearer?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plausible enough title in headline syntax. I wouldn't know precisely what you meant from it, but that is true of a great many titles, and as long as reading the following text explained it, that's fine.

Whether I would agree that it was a *good* title is impossible to say without knowing why you chose the word *segmentation*, but as long as that became obvious upon reading the rest of the piece, then that seems fine.

Comment: Do you think that i should make it more clear? for people that are outside my field to understand it? Or as you said when they read the rest they'll understand

Comment: I would say that because of *streams* it's a garden-path title and thus more cumbersome than it needs to be. At the very least I'd make it "Document-Stream Segmentation and Classification". But really, "Segmentation and Classification of Document Streams" is much clearer, and you get additional emphasis on *segmentation and classification*, which are the whole point of the paper.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Exactly the objective of the paper is the segmentation and classification of documents. Very interesting thank you

Comment: Yes, I favour @RegDwigнt's suggestion, though your original is fine too. Titles and headings sacrifice precision for concision, and the balance is not something one can give a perfect guide on, but a matter of judgement. Once upon a time (around the 18th Century) it was common to have very long and detailed titles and headings which would go on for several sentences, but people ended up creating their own abridged titles anyway.